# std::is_const identifies const pointer as non-const

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am puzzled by `std::is_const`'s behaviour in identifying a `const` pointer as non-`const`.
My own implementation of `is_const` does exactly the same thing. I'm not sure why the more general templated struct `<T>`is being picked over the `<const T>` version. Both gcc4.7 and clang3.1-svn show the same behaviour. Can anyone explain what's going on? Code is given below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <type_traits>

class CEmptyClass {}; 

namespace jbc 
{
  template <typename T>
  struct is_const : std::false_type {}; 

  template <typename T>
  struct is_const<const T> : std::true_type {}; 
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::cout << "Is 'const CEmptyClass*' constant according to std lib : " 
    << std::is_const<const CEmptyClass*>::value << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Is 'const CEmptyClass*' constant according to jbc : " 
    << jbc::is_const<const CEmptyClass*>::value << std::endl;
}
```

In both instances `is_const<const CEmptyClass*>::value` returns `0`

Comment: *I am puzzled by `std::is_const`'s behaviour in identifying a const pointer as non-const.* There is no *const pointer* in the code, only *non-const pointer to const*

Comment: You're quite right. I was thinking of pointer to const as being const, which it's not.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no such thing as a `const` reference, a reference is never `const`. Code like this does not compile:

```
int& const i;
```

Now if you were to remove your reference, it would work. If you were to place `const` on the right side (semantically is the same thing), and read the type backwards

```
CEmptyClass const&
```

it would read a *reference* to a *const*  *CEmptyClass*, **not** a *const*  *reference* to an *CEmptyClass*.

**Update:** Now that you changed the reference to a pointer, the same misconstruction persist:

```
const CEmptyClass*
CEmptyClass const*
```

both are the same, a **non-const** pointer to a const CEmptyClass

```
CEmptyClass* const
```

is a **const** pointer to a CEmptyClass

and

```
const CEmptyClass* const
CEmptyClass const* const
```

are a **const** pointer to a const CEmptyClass.

Comment: True. Changing the reference to a pointer (question and code updated) still leaves the mysterious behaviour in place. Why is `const T*` not `const` ?

Comment: @j code: `const T*` is the same as `T const*` which is a _pointer_ to a _const_  _T_, again **NOT** `const`. Also, `T* const` or `const T* const` or `T const* const` would be `const`.

Comment: "and read the type backwards" - genius, a way to read these compound declarations at last...